# Passing Data between Views Using Segue Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, segue

I have this Login page with a Button. When the Button is pressed I want to switch view using the Segue, and most importantly, pass the data along.

I have this Code:

```
TabBarViewController *tvc = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"BEFORE: %@", tvc.user); //OUTPUTS NULL

tvc.user = @"HELLO";
NSLog(@"AFTER: %@", tvc.user); //OUTPUTS HELLO

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomain" sender:sender];
```

It does not work. I try to do a `NSLog` on the user property in the tvc class, and it is NULL.

However, this code, that is attached to the Button works:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"meeh"] ) {
        TabBarViewController *tvc =[segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"BEFORE: %@", tvc.user);

        tvc.user = @"Hello";
        NSLog(@"AFTER: %@", tvc.user);

    }
}
```

When I do `NSLog` on the user property in tvc class, I get "Hello", and therefore it works.

I want to use the first option, `performSegueWithIdentifier`, because that allows me to only go to the next View, if and only if a condition is met - that is whether the login is valid. However, I cannot pass the variable correctly. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are calling the segue with name "gotomain" and you are checking the segue with name "meeh"

Comment: Your prepareForSegue method will automatically initialize TabBarViewController at this line TabBarViewController *tvc =[segue destinationViewController] so you can check conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

You need both `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomain" sender:sender];` and `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`.

You also need to check `tvc.user` before `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
if ([tvc.user isEqualToString:@"valid_username_here"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomain" sender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code example doesn't work because you are creating a new instance of TabBarViewController with alloc init -- this is not the instance that you have in your storyboard. You seem to be confused about what performSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue are used for. prepareForSegue is called when a segue is initiated -- no matter how it is initiated, whether that be in code, or directly from a UI element. That is the method you should use to pass data, because it gives you access to the destinationViewController.

performSegueWithIdentifier triggers a segue. If you want a conditional segue, you connect the segue in the storyboard from one controller to another controller -- this segue will not be performed until you call performSegueWithIdentifier in code (which you can do after whatever conditions you want to be met, are met). If you connect the segue from a button (or a tableViewCell), performSegueWithIdentifier is called for you (you don't call it yourself), and so you can't set any condition on the segue -- it will be executed as soon as you touch the button.

Answer (score 0):

To create a view controller object you have two ways, one is mentioned below

```
TabBarViewController *tvc = (TabBarViewController *)[mainStoryboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"storyboardIdOfTabBarViewController"];
```

Here you can pass the value `tvc.user = @"Hello"`.

Another way is use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method. When you want to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method then you must use `prepareForSegue` delegate method to pass the values to `destinationViewController`. For conditional navigations you should set the segue from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller.You have to use the `segue.identifier` in the `prepareForSegue` method so that you will get the object of the `destinationViewController` from `segue.destinationViewController` property.